# ¿Dónde se encuentra la clase WorkbookFactory en Apache POI 3.14?

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

Estoy creando un pequeño ejemplo para trabajar con archivos Excel. Usualmente los creo desde 0 para utilizar las últimas versiones de las librerías. En este caso, trabajo con Apache POI 3.14 que ha sido lanzada en Marzo de 2016 y maven. Tengo este pequeño código para abrir un archivo Excel guardado en disco:

```
File file = new File(/* ruta de mi archivo */);
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

Pero el IDE me lanza un error en `WorkbookFactory`, indica que no existe dicha clase. Recuerdo haber trabajado hasta con POI 3.11 y no tenía este problema. ¿Alguien sabe dónde se encuentra esta clase ahora?

Mi configuración de la dependencia en el pom:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscando en internet, encontré [la respuesta de @Gagravarr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33694617/1065197) que indica que esta clase ahora se encuentra en la librería OOXML de POI desde la versión 3.13. Esta sería la solución en maven, agregar la dependencia requerida:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
<!--
    Agregar la dependencia a poi-ooxml
    Verificar que sean la misma versión
-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
```